# What tag should I use for a Spoons-related question?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

I have a question about the game of Spoons.  (Unless the comments indicate otherwise, I'll assume that readers know what this game is.)  **I'm wondering what tag I should use for this question, or if I should even ask this question.**  Board & Card Games Stack Exchange does not have a Spoons tag.  What should I do?

NOTE: I'm not asking that a Spoons tag be created, since there's like only one pre-existing question about Spoons.

Answer (score 6):

Go ahead, ask the question.  Don't worry about the tags.  We've got a fair number of people who will edit your post later and fix up the tag.

We prefer any question about a specific game be tagged with that game name (and generally not too much else).  It isn't something that a newer user needs to worry about though.  Just use any tag that's handy.

Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 1):

> I have a question about a game for which there is no tag. What do I do?

I think this is good justification for creating a new tag, at least for as long as this community continues to categorize questions by the name of the game. If we move to a system where we tag questions according to some kind of "category" (zombies, war, cooperative, etc.) then things might change.

It's okay if you're the first or second person to ask about a game. Go ahead and create the tag.

> I don't have enough reputation to create tags. What do I do?

Unfortunately, the system won't let you tag a question using the [untagged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag. Pick a tag that clearly does not fit your question, and use that one instead. Then, put a bold sentence at the top of your post like "This should be tagged [spoons](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoons), but that tag doesn't exist, and I don't have enough reputation to create it. Please retag."

Comment: During the edit grace period, I removed the suggestion to flag with a custom moderator flag. I decided this isn't really something a moderator is required to fix, since any high rep user can do it. Plus, I'm not a mod. I'll let the mods ask for more flags to handle. :P